# How to create a custom route inside resource without overwrite path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, seo

I’ve this on routes.rb

```
resources :questions, except: [:show] do
   get '/resource/:subject/:id', to: 'resource#show', as: "resource", param: [:name, :id]
```

It says that:

> Invalid route name, already in use: ‘resource' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming

I know that resources create two routes with the same path, `show` and `destroy` both uses `resource_path`, how does it is being created internally? and how i can generate my route for show  wihtout overwrite the one in destroy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to eliminate  routes unneeded is by specifying the :only option

```
resources :user, :only => [:edit]
```

instead of

```
resources :user, :except => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you could take out show and then define the route that you want separately. See if this works:

```
resources :questions, except: :show

get '/resource/:subject/:id',
  to: 'resource#show',
  as: "resource",  # This is where the error is.
  param: [:name, :id]
```

**EDIT**: Ah, yes. The :as parameter needs a different name. This will work:

```
resources :questions, except: :show

get '/resource/:subject/:id',
  to: 'resource#show',
  as: "resource_show",
  param: [:name, :id]
```